# Call angularJS controller function from index.html javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I created a Ionic, AngularJS, phonegap/cordova app.

In my index.html I have this snippet of pure javascript:

```
  <script src="js/analytics/launchMyApp.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    function handleOpenURL(url) {
        // This function is triggered by the LaunchMyApp Plugin
        setTimeout(function() {
        alert("Hey the URL: " + url);
        console.log(">>>>>>>>> Take me to the launchMyApp controller: " + url);

        // Call controller function here

        }, 3000);
    }

</script>
```

The handleOpenURL function is triggered from the launchMyApp plugin:

```
  nl.x-services.plugins.launchmyapp
```

Here is my controller:

```
  communicatorApp.controller('LaunchMyAppCtrl', function($scope, $state) {

     console.log(">>>>>>>> COOL!!!!");

     $scope.launchMyAppHere = function(urlIn) {
         console.log(">>>>>>>> GO MAN GO: " + urlIn);
     };

  });
```

My issue is I do not know how to call the launchMyAppHere function from the index.html javascript?

Comment: That's still not very clear. This question needs a serious overhaul if you want help.

Comment: See my accepted answer - someone DID understand me ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
angular.element($("#elementID")).scope().launchMyAppHere();
```

where `#elementID` is DOM ID of element where you attach you controller.

Comment: @lulu88 can you share the code in the index.html that worked for you?